# Como colocar este article alineado con los demas

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Tengo un problema, esto me pasa cuando on responsive hago la pantalla mas pequeña ya que el texto no cabe:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Son 4 articles en cols de Bootstrap, he intentado darle clearfix detrás de todos los article así todos deberían agrandarse, pero no va. Mi única solución fue darle `padding:0`, le quito lo que antes tenia asi no me estorba, pero es una forma muy pobre, ¿alguna idea de cómo solucionarlo?

Éste es mi código:

```css
/*------------- GENERAL ------------*/
body {
  /*NOT NECESSARY*/
  /*overflow-x: hidden;*/
  color: #8d8d8d;
}

i:not(.sinColorSepia) {
  color: rgb(122, 76, 30);
}

section {
  padding: 70px 0;
}

.row {
  padding: 12px 0;
}

/*---------------SECTION 2 ARTICLES---------------*/

section:nth-child(2) {
  padding: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #000 url('../img/backgrounds/bg-skills.jpg') no-repeat fixed center / cover;
  color: white;
}

.section2 i {
  font-size: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.relativoParaVelo {
  position: relative;
}

.section2 article div {
  font-size: 30px;
  position: relative;
}

.section2 article {
  border: 1px solid white;
  padding: 30px;
  position: relative;
}

.section2 article::before {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .08);
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

.section2 article p {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-style: oblique;
}

/*------------------------COLORES LINEAS----------------------------*/

@media screen and (max-width: 1028px) {
  .section2 article {
    /*padding: 20px;*/
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
  /*------------------------GENERAL----------------------------*/
  .section2 article {
    margin: 10px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300|Montserrat|Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Estilos -->
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap-reboot.css">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap-grid.css">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">


<main>

  <section class="section2">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
          <article>
            <i class="fa fa-sliders sinColorSepia"></i>
            <div>752</div>
            <p class="diferenteArticleNoPadding relativoParaVelo">Proyectos realizados</p>
          </article>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
          <article>
            <i class="fa fa-sitemap sinColorSepia"></i>
            <div>495</div>
            <p class="diferenteArticleNoPadding relativoParaVelo">Clientes satisfechos</p>
          </article>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
          <article>
            <i class="fa fa-paper-plane-o sinColorSepia"></i>
            <div>16</div>
            <p class="diferenteArticleNoPadding relativoParaVelo">Premios ganados</p>
          </article>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
          <article>
            <i class="fa fa-puzzle-piece sinColorSepia"></i>
            <div>+900</div>
            <p class="diferenteArticleNoPadding relativoParaVelo">Litros de café</p>
          </article>
          <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

</main>
```

Comment: Podría darle un max-heigth a los article

Comment: Hola francisco dwq, como te comentaba en otra pregunta que hiciste, debes reducir el problema al mínimo. El código que compartes tiene dos problemas de formato: 1) incluye mucho más que el problema en sí, creando ruido; 2) no muestra el problema que comentas. Lee [ask] y cómo crear un [mcve] donde encontrarás consejos para crear preguntas de calidad. Y también completa el [tour] para ver cómo funciona el sitio.

Comment: Intenta quitándole padding de izquierda y derecha con `padding-left y padding-right`, el padding es el espacio que deja entre el borde y el elemento.

Comment: Aparte, deberías mirar otras preguntas del sitio. Estoy convencido de que esta pregunta ya se ha realizado antes y tiene respuesta en Stack Overflow en español.

Comment: Hay muchas formas de solucionarlo, con los paddings con flex, etc. Pero el código que proporcionas no se reproduce exactamente lo que dices. Entonces cualquier cosa que digamos puede que no te funcione en tu caso especifico.

Answer (score 0):

yo lo veo sencillo de solucionar, al .col-lg-3 lo conviertes en un padre flexible y al article pasa a ser un hijo flexible y le agregas la siguiente propiedad flex: 1 0 auto;

te queda de la siguiente manera:

```
 .col-lg-3{
     display: flex;
 }
 article{
     flex: 1 0 auto;
 }
```